# LightGBM: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, lightgbm

I was running `lightgbm` with categorical features:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_X, train_y, test_size=0.3)

train_data = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train, feature_name=X_train.columns, 
                                  categorical_feature=cat_features)

test_data = lgb.Dataset(X_test, label=y_train, reference=train_data)

param = {'num_trees': 4000, 'objective':'binary', 'metric': 'auc'}
bst = lgb.train(param, train_data, valid_sets=[test_data], early_stopping_rounds=100)
```

Turns out the Error:

> if self.handle is not None and feature_name is not None and
>   feature_name != 'auto':
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I checked the other similar errors on stackoverflow mostly related to `numpy`, and I then checked documentation and tried to replace my `categorical_feature` with index like `[0, 2, 5, ...]`(my original was column names of categorical features), still the same error.

I also tried replacing `label` with the column index, still error.

Anyone could help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also all my categorical features have been LabelEncoded

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, there is an issue with the way how you pass `feature_name`. The constructor expects a list, and oyu pass it `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`. The problem is that on such object `feature_name != 'auto'` condition from the if statement that the error mentions acts element-wise. Thus the `or` tries to join a `bool` and `numpy.ndarray`.

A simple solution would be either to convert to a list (`feature_name=X_train.columns.tolist()`) or to use `feature_name='auto'`, which will the name extraction from a `pd.DataFrame` internally

Answer (score 0):

I also find that drop `feature_name` works.

```
train_data = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train, categorical_feature=cat_features)
test_data = lgb.Dataset(X_test, label=y_test, reference=train_data)

param = {'num_trees': 4000, 'objective':'binary', 'metric': 'auc'}
bst = lgb.train(param, train_data, valid_sets=[test_data], early_stopping_rounds=100)
```

Comment: This happens because `feature_name='auto'` is the default